# How do you calculate the total and percent overhead added by TCP, IP and link (IEEE 802.3) layer encapsulations?

Tags: percentages

I need help figuring out how to compute the total and percent overhead added by TCP, IP and link (IEEE 802.3) layer encapsulations for each of the following message sizes:74 bytes,152 bytes,3000 bytes

I know the header size for TCP= 20 bytes with no options, IP=20 bytes with no options, and IEEE 802.3 header size= 26 bytes but not sure how to get total overhead and percent overhead for each

Comment: Sounds like your firm needs to hire a consultant.